# Submit APK to Google Play using API

Tags: android

Is there any official API  that enables me to automatically upload an APK to Google Play?

I´ve seen the same question in 2013 but now, in 2014 is anytthing relevant with it?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing official.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @One seemed like it should be a comment. IMHO, the answer on the dupe is much better. "Nothing official, you'd have to do it yourself through XYZ, here's a project to do this in the works". But [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156941/one-liner-answers) seems to think they're okay, so I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: sure, maybe if there was some way of providing references, it would have been better. Depends on the question though, sometimes these answers are worthy of deletion and other times not.

Comment: @One upon reflection, I think you're right. While this answer could be better, it doesn't need to be deleted. Thanks for the head check, I made a bad call.